# Use cookieless or session-cookie in ASP.NET MVC 5's UseCookieAuthentication()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, which using the cookie authetication. However, after running penetration tests, it was vulnerable to MITM attack, where this cookie can be re-used if is stolen.

```
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login")
});
```

1. My question is: how to invalidate / expire this cookie upon logout? (not the cookie itself, but the value of the cookie uses by ASP.NET)
2. This cookie appears to be not under the control of `web.config`'s `sessionState`, where it can be stored in memory. Can cookie above be configured to store as session cookie?

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" ... />
```

3. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own ITicketStore to keep the value in session. Your implementation goes into the SessionStore of the CookieOptions. Although I wouldn't use InProc. This will enable you to kill it upon logout. The other thing is you should set the ExpireTimeSpan.

The MITM attack would technically still work, but this makes it slightly harder. To mitigate it further you should be doing other things such as using https and tls 1.3.

Comment: thanks. Is it something that similar to this: https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity-update ?

Comment: regarding to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan?view=aspnetcore-1.1, it's counted from the creation time, not the disposing time, where attcker could be slipped-in thru' this range

Comment: and ITicketStore appears to be only available in MVC .net core, not MVC5 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?search=ITicketStore&category=All&skip=0

Comment: @gangary sorry, my neighborhood is under siege, will try to get back when life goes back to normal.